# Textview not working in setRetainInstance

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview, orientation

This is making me so fed up. No matter how I tried I cannot retain the state of textview upon the device is rotated.

The following is sample:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="387dp"
        android:layout_height="103dp"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change Text"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**RotationFragmentDemo.java**

```
package com.rotationfragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class RotationFragmentDemo extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // This check returns 'null' for the first time when there are no fragments
        if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {

            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, new RotationFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

**RotationFragment.java**

```
  package com.rotationfragment;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RotationFragment extends Fragment implements
        View.OnClickListener {

    TextView textView;

    String myText;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // This should help to retain fragment
        setRetainInstance(true);

        View result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);

        result.findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(this);

        if (textView == null)
            textView = (TextView)result.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        else
            textView.setText(myText);

        return(result);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        textView.setText("Hello.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        myText = textView.getText().toString();
    }
}
```

In the debug mode when the device is rotated, I clearly see the Text is set to textview in `onCreateView` at line `textView.setText(myText);` but still this is not working as expected.

Comment: why you don't use `savedInstanceState` in `onCreateView` to restore state?

Comment: It doesn't work because I am using `setRetainFragment`. Also, I need to use `setRetainFragment` in my case for other stuff where `savedInstanceState` won't work e.g to retain `Socket` and `Thread` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the `Fragment` is retained (*myText* keeps its value after an orientation change) but there will be a new set of `View`s, and so you have to bind to them in `onCreateView()` or your code will keep referring to the now invisible `View`s

Just for testing, I used the following method

```
@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    boolean same = (textView.equals(getView().findViewById(R.id.textView)));
    Log.d(TAG, "onViewStateRestored: TextViews are same object:" + same);
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
}
```

and got the following Logcat entry after rotating the device:

> com.example.retainedrotationapplication D/RotationFragment: onViewStateRestored: TextViews are same object:false

So you have skip the null check in `onCreateView()` and write

```
textView = (TextView)result.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Comment: The views in the fragment will be re-created but the fragment is retained? I thought by using `if (textView == null)`I was controlling whether to create new view or not. So, I guess they are created on inflation if I am right.

Comment: Before I ran your code I also would have thought that the Fragment with everything that belongs to it will be kept the way it is ( I did read things like "retained Fragments make sense for retaining data" somewhere but never questioned what would happen to the Views). But you don't cause a View to be created by calling `findViewById()`. You just get a handle to it. It is created as part of the layout xml you inflated.

Comment: So just maybe one could store the root View and return it in  `onCreateView()`. But this would not always make sense.

Comment: Okay, that was informative and good information to understand the process behind it. Now, the reason I am using `onSaveInstanceState` is because `onConfigurationChanged` doesn't work for me. Any idea if that is because I am using fragment to handle `onConfigurationChanged`?

Comment: Is it just about preserving the text of the TextView ?

Comment: Then you can use `android:freezesText="true" ` as attribute for the TextView. This will cause the text to stay unchanged after a config change. By default the text will be reset to the value from the layout.

Comment: Yes, this sounds like a better solution. I'll test it. I'll be going to preserve other data in fragment in future as well which could be a `Thread`, `Activity` or other stuff which cannot be parcelable.

Comment: As for overriding `onConfigurationChanged()` - if you're doing this to save the state of your application, then IMO you should use `onSaveInstanceState()` etc. because every time the app experiences a config change it will need to save its state but there are other events beside config changes where you also want the user to be able to return to your app and find things the way they were.

Answer (score 0):

You retain fragment, but when you rotate screen, activity recalls `onCreate` method and this redraws your `RotationFragment`. You can force for saving with this manifest line.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```